# Detecting if a string contains a "real sentence"?

Tags: detect

Is there some library out there that can figure out if a given string of characters contains a "real sentence" in English, meaning that it contains words from English? (The sentence need not make sense, but it should contains real English words)

For example, the following is not a sentence (at least in English:) -

```
hsgdhjf asdf dsusdf udfhpiew
```

Comment: "What's. A. Real. Sentence?" ...asked William Shatner.

Comment: Do colorless green ideas sleep furiously? The vertebral silence indisposes the licit sail, the gostak distims the doshes. Markov chains FTW!

Comment: Updated the question to make what I meant clearer

Comment: Some stuff [here](http://code.google.com/p/olac/wiki/Enrichment)

Comment: So to clarify, are you saying you want to find out if all the words in a whitespace-delimited string are real English words? If that's all there is to the question, it's not that hard, but people have so far been (understandably) misinterpreting it.

Comment: That was my intent, but I posed the question wrongly (had updated it). People already had posted replies and they were valid for that question..their answers have given me a lot to chew on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unsolved problem, as computers have no idea of what "makes sense". Even if it tries to parse a sentence by detecting nouns, verbs, etc, there are still phrases like ["colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) or ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) that would get through. I doubt many people would say those are sentences.

There are also multiple ways of parsing sentences, for example "Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana" can be parsed as:

- adjective noun verb article noun; noun verb preposition article noun
- noun verb preposition article noun; adjective noun verb article noun

to take just two ways.

The bottom line: parsing natural language is **hard**, and making sense of it is even harder.

Comment: Side note: of the two parsings listed above (there are others), the first doesn't make sense because, as far as we know, there are no such things as "time flies". The second half of the first parsing does make sense, of course.

Comment: I think all he really cares about is something like putting all the words of a sentance into an array and qualifying them one by one against a dictionary database, which would of course be slow, but would do what he wanted.

Comment: Yes -- since the question was updated :-) The original question was ambiguous, so I assumed the most difficult thing was being asked. As a side note, a dictionary lookup shouldn't necessarily be that slow, assuming it's stored well (e.g. a DAWG)

Comment: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo, right?

Comment: @Dave, "Time flies" is a common idiom used to indicate that time seems to have passed quickly and in this sense "Time flies like an arrow" is a valid sentence ... just to be pedantic.

Comment: @Brian, it is indeed -- but you need to have that knowledge. If you don't, you might assume that there is a type of fly called a "time fly", which is fond of arrows, in the same way that there is a type of fly called a "fruit fly", which is fond of bananas.

Answer (score 3):

You can ensure that every word is spelled correctly using a spelling checker (there are a number of libraries for this, none of which I have used) but that still won't tell you if the sentence is grammatical. Furthermore, an English speaker would probably consider a sentence "real" even if it had some errors, and some words aren't in the dictionary.

The best way to do this remains to have your program show the alleged sentence to a human being who speaks English, and ask them if it is a "real sentence."